# how to get parameters from a specific field of row in gridView for a templatefield at the same row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource, templatefield

I'm using GridView to display data from dataBase, the gridView is bound to objectDataSource.
each row in gridview represent an item that belongs to user and I want to add another field to the gridView that will display the users detail (that actually are in a different table at the dataBase).

I'm not sure what is the best way to do that,
I tried to add to the gridView a TemplateField that contain a DetailView,
and bound it to another objectdatasource but I don't know how to take a parameter from a specific field at the row-(the userID field).

Any suggestions would be welcome...

Comment: Why not just do a join on the sql table to also retrieve the users details, then bind that to the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a little trickier than that. You can set the userID as a data key, and in the RowDataBound event of the GridView, bind the detail view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //get the data key
    int userID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["UserID"];

    //get the nested details view control
    DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)e.Row.FindControl("DetailsView1");

    dv.DataSource = GetUserDetailsTable(userID); //your data source
    dv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried that but I have got an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"    the marked line:  int userID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["contactID"];

Comment: Did you define the Datakeys in the ASPX?

Comment: You have to specify contactID in the DataKeyNames property of the ASPX.

Comment: thanks for your help, I probably had to add the condition " if(e.Row.RowIndex>-1) "...cause now that exception was gone but I have got into another problem- my queries returns objects(I'm working with entities) and when I write DetailsView1.DataSource=accessToDB.GetContactByID(userID); I get the exception: "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource"...

Comment: you shouldn't need to add that condition, but I guess if it's working that's cool. As for your other error, that's because your object isn't a bindable data source. You'll have to make the object bindable, or find another way around it.